# Saving Mipmap files

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

So, I am almost done with building my program that creates mipmaps. It will successfully upload an image of your choosing, and create mipmaps of that image, but now the last part is where I am stuck.

I now want for the the user to be able to save his or her mipmaps, but I am not sure how. I want them to be able to save it anywhere they want, and I have a feeling it will require a dialoq box, but I only know how to implement dialog boxes when opening items, not saving them.

Here is my code so far:

```
from __future__ import division
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL
from PyQt4.QtGui import * #Used to import QPixmap. DO NOT REMOVE.
from PyQt4.QtCore import * #Used to import Qt.KeepAspectRation. DO NOT REMOVE.
import sys, os
import mmCreator


class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, mmCreator.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnSelect.clicked.connect(self.select_image)
        self.btnConvert.clicked.connect(self.mipmap)
        self.btnDownload.clicked.connect(self.download)


    def select_image(self):
        self.origImage.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.origImage.clear()
        global image
        image = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                              "Select Image",
                                              "",
                                              "Image File (*.jpg *.png *.gif)")
        global pixmap
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        scaledPixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.origImage.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.origImage.setPixmap(scaledPixmap)
        self.origImage.show()


    def mipmap(self):
        self.mipMap.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        #Create scaled versions of the source image.
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        global mipmaps
        mipmaps = []
        #Version 1 goes up to 1/16 of original size.
        mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 2))
        mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 4))
        mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 8))
        mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 16))
        #Show the first mipmapped version of the image, at 75% label size.
        scaledMipMap = mipmaps[0].scaled(self.mipMap.size() * (3/4), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.mipMap.setPixmap(scaledMipMap)
        self.mipMap.show()

    def download():
        mipmaps.save('/path/to/file.png', 'PNG')

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = MyApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName

Comment: Okay, but then where do I put `mipmaps` in getSaveFileName?

Comment: you don't. You get the path where to save with the dialog, and then you save the image. Just like to load: get the path, then create a `QPixMap`

Comment: Okay, so I have the getSaveFileName set up, but I just can't seem to save an image. I set a mipmap array value to a new QPixmap as such:
`pixmap2 = QPixmap(mipmaps[0])`, and then 'pixmap2 = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save Image", "","Image File (*.jpg *.png *.gif)")`

But nothing saves. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open/save any documents, there are two steps:

1. **Get the path** as a string, for example `"/home/Documents/myImage.png"`. One way to get the path is to ask the user in a dialog.
   Qt provides methods to do this, one being `getSaveFileName()`. From the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName):

   > This is a convenience static function that will return a file name
   >   selected by the user. The file does not have to exist.

   This methods returns a file name: it does not save anything.
2. **Open or save the document**, using the path.
   To load the image, you used `pixmap = QPixmap(imagePath)`
   To save it, you can use `pixmap.save(imagePath)` ([doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#save))